# DB2 on delete trigger causing deadlock

Tags: database, db2, deadlock, ibm-db2

When trying to run a delete query on the parent table I am getting locked. Following is the table structure and executing this *" DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = 1; "* would create a deadlock -

------------------Create related tables-----------------------------

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT (
    PARENT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PARENT_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE CHILD_ONE (
    CHILD_ONE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHILD_ONE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SELF_REFERNCE_ID INT,
    LANGUAGE_ID INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TWO (
    CHILD_TWO_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHILD_ONE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY INT,
    LANGUAGE_ID INT NOT NULL
);
```

-----------------------Create indexes on tables-----------------------------

```
ALTER TABLE PARENT ADD CONSTRAINT PARENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (PARENT_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID,LANGUAGE_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_ONE ADD CONSTRAINT SELF_REFERNCE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (SELF_REFERNCE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_TWO_PK PRIMARY KEY (CHILD_TWO_ID,LANGUAGE_ID);
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_TWO_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_TWO_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TWO ADD CONSTRAINT CHILD_ONE_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ONE_ID) REFERENCES PARENT (PARENT_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

-----------------------------Create triggers tables-----------------------------

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHILD_ONE_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON CHILD_ONE 
REFERENCING OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = O.CHILD_ONE_ID;

CREATE TRIGGER CHILD_TWO_TRIGGER AFTER DELETE ON CHILD_TWO
REFERENCING OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM PARENT WHERE PARENT_ID = O.CHILD_TWO_ID;
```

---------------Insert Records--------------------------------------------

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (2,'CHILD_ONE-2');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (3,'CHILD_ONE-3');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (4,'CHILD_TWO-1');
INSERT INTO PARENT (PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME) VALUES (5,'CHILD_TWO-2');

INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1', NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1,'CHILD_ONE-1', NULL, 2);
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (2,'CHILD_ONE-2', 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO CHILD_ONE (CHILD_ONE_ID, CHILD_ONE_NAME, SELF_REFERNCE_ID, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (3,'CHILD_ONE-3', 2, 2 );

INSERT INTO CHILD_TWO (CHILD_TWO_ID, CHILD_ONE_ID, QUANTITY, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (4, 1, 501, 1);
INSERT INTO CHILD_TWO (CHILD_TWO_ID, CHILD_ONE_ID, QUANTITY, LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (5, 2, 501, 1);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why have a referential constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE and a trigger on the child that deletes the parent?  Seems to me you're deleting in circles...deadlock isn't a surprise.

Comment: I want to clear off rows from parent which are not being referenced anywhere. My question is if it's in same transaction it shouldn't cause deadlock, right?

Comment: Which version and platform, please?

Comment: Hmm... from the look of things, even if it reused transactions, you're still not allowed to do re-entrant cascades; attempting to do this should throw an error anyways.  You'd likely have a better time either rethinking your design slightly (you support many-to-one, but delete if **any** of the rows goes away, which could be a problem), or just periodically run a clean-up script.

Comment: It's DB2 Express-C version 10.5.